# docker compose 3.1(swarm), secrets, ssl and nginx

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I have a nginx running inside a docker container. In the nginx conf file inside the server block, I have put in the ssl config – the port, the crt and the key. The simplest possible way for nginx to find the crt and key files is that I create a docker secret for the 2 files and it gets mounted at /run/secrets/ when the service is spawned. I however, want to have the crt and key files inside the docker image which can be like out of the box files that nginx can use and if a customer creates a secret, and plugs the crt and key files, I want nginx to use those.

Going by the 3.1 compose file docs for secret, I have realized that either the secret must pre-exist or must be created as a part of compose file. Now the challenge is, if it must pre-exist, then I am enforcing the customer to create a secret(which means not only create a secret but also have crt and key files ready to be given as input to the create secret command). If I create it in the compose file, I still need access to the crt and key files that customer must provide. Which means, in either case, the thing does not work out of the box.

How do I solve this?

If someone has read this far and still has not lost interest, even if above gets solved, the other issue I am facing is that in the nginx conf, I cannot specify 2 certificates in the order of priority in which to pick them under the same server block. Anyone has any idea on this too?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for you is creating a custom entrypoint script for the NGINX container in conjunction with environment variables and a 'template' nginx.conf. Those will take care of the proper certificates configuration.

Your script will look something like (given Alpine image):

```
#!/bin/sh

if  [ -z $CERTS_FOLDER ]; then CERTS_FOLDER="/etc/nginx/default_crts/"; fi
sed -i "s|{CERTS_FOLDER}|${CERTS_FOLDER}|g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

And the matching section in your nginx.conf will be like:

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    ssl                     on;
    server_name             my-server;
    ssl_certificate         {CERTS_FOLDER}my-server.crt;
    ...
```

This way you can provide some out-of-the box certificates and override them using the [compose environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).